# Interface to enumerate over files

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented, .net, iterator

I'm trying to design a generic interface for enumerating over a list files. Each iteration will open a file, allow the consuming code to access the file to perform some task, and then close the file.

At first this seemed like like a simple enumeration pattern, but the consuming code actually needs to know the status of each file both after it is opened and after it is closed. So rather then having a single `MoveNext()` method my interface has `OpenNextFile()` and `CloseCurrentFile()` methods, each of which may return a failure status. In addition, `CloseCurrentFile()` needs a way to report whether each file was saved or not when it was closed.

Here's my current interface.

```
public interface IFileEnumerator
{
    //The following properties reflect the current state of the IFileEnumerator
    FileEnumeratorStatus Status { get; }
    string StatusMessage { get; }
    string FileName { get; }
    byte[] FileData { get; }

    //Attempts to open the next file
    FileEnumeratorStatus OpenNextFile();

    //Closes the current file
    FileEnumeratorStatus CloseCurrentFile();
}


public enum FileEnumeratorStatus
{ 
    AtStart, //Files have not been opened
    Opened, //File currently opened
    Opened_Failed, //Failed to open file
    Close_Saved, //File closed and saved
    Closed_NotSaved, //File closed and not saved
    Close_SaveFailed, //File closed saving failed
    AtEnd //No more files
}
```

Here's an example of the consuming code:

```
//FileProcessor is a class which run a ProcesssJob on a set of files returned by a     
//IFileEnumerator and returns a ProcesssingJobResult with results of all the files 
public class FileProcessor
{
    public ProcesssingJobResult RunJob(IFileEnumerator fileEnumerator, ProcesssJob job)
    {
        List<FileProcessingResult> resultList = new List<FileProcessingResult>();

        while (fileEnumerator.OpenNextFile() != FileEnumeratorStatus.AtEnd)
        {
            FileProcessingResult currentFileResult = new FileProcessingResult();
            currentFileResult.FileName = fileEnumerator.FileName;

            if (fileEnumerator.Status == FileEnumeratorStatus.Opened)
            {
                currentFileResult.JobCompleted = job.RunJob(fileEnumerator.FileData);

                var closureStatus = fileEnumerator.CloseCurrentFile();

                if (closureStatus == FileEnumeratorStatus.Close_Saved)
                    currentFileResult.Saved = true;
                else if (closureStatus == FileEnumeratorStatus.Closed_NotSaved)
                    currentFileResult.Saved = false;
                else if (closureStatus == FileEnumeratorStatus.Close_SaveFailed)
                {
                    currentFileResult.Saved = false;
                    currentFileResult.Message = fileEnumerator.StatusMessage;
                }
            }
            else if (fileEnumerator.Status == FileEnumeratorStatus.Opened_Failed)
            {
                currentFileResult.JobCompleted = false;
                currentFileResult.Message = fileEnumerator.StatusMessage;
                currentFileResult.Saved = false;
            }

            resultList.Add(currentFileResult);
        }

        ProcesssingJobResult jobresult = new ProcesssingJobResult();
        jobresult.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        jobresult.Machine = System.Environment.MachineName;
        jobresult.User = System.Environment.UserName;
        jobresult.Results = resultList;

        return jobresult;
    }
}

//A generic task that can be run on a file
public interface ProcesssJob
{
    bool RunJob(byte[] data);
}

//Result of processing one file
public class FileProcessingResult
{
    public bool JobCompleted { get; set; }
    public bool Saved { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

}

//The overall result of processing a set of files
public class ProcesssingJobResult
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public String Machine { get; set; }
    public String User { get; set; }
    public List<FileProcessingResult> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe this is just a question of careful documentation, but I'm having trouble dealing with all these different possible states. Drawing a state diagram doesn't help as it's possible to go from every state to just about every other state. Should the consuming code call CloseCurrentFile() if OpenNextFile() return Open_Failed? What if it does? Would a Closed status be returned even if a file was never opened? If CloseCurrentFile() was not called after OpenNextFile() should it be closed automatically by the next call to OpenNextFile() or should an exception be thrown? I'd rather someone implementing this interface not have to worry about getting all this right.

The problem is much simpler if I have a single OpenNextFile() method which is responsible for both closing the last opened file, and opening the next file. Yet then this single method needs to report both the result of opening the next file, as well as closing the last file. This also becomes tricky for consuming code as the final state of each file is not determined until the following iteration.

```
public interface IFileEnumerator_Alternate
{
    string FileName { get; }
    byte[] FileData { get; }
    string StatusMessage {get;}

    //Closes the previous file, and opens the next file
    Result OpenNextFile();
}

public class Result
{
    public bool CurrentFileOpened {get; set;}
    public string CurrentFileName {get; set;}
    public string CurrentFileStatusMessage {get; set;}

    public string LastFileName {get; set;}
    public bool LastFileClosedOk {get; set;}
    public string LastFileClosedStatusMessage {get; set;}
    public bool LastFileSaved {get; set;}
}
```

Is there another way to look at this, or some other common design pattern that is more suited to what I'm trying to do? Here's an activity diagram showing the overall process.

[image: Activity Diagram]

Comment: Can you show the actual consuming code?

Comment: I don't have any actual consuming code yet, but I updated the example in my question to be closer to what I've been thinking.

Comment: Does the enumerator also handle closing/saving or is that part of the processor?

Comment: Also, it is necessary to synchronize between files (eg. is it possible to process/open multiple files at once), or is this synchronized?

Comment: Yes the "enumerator" handles closing and saving. Basically I don't want the processor class to have to worry about where the data came from at all. Maybe it is just a file on a drive. Maybe the data had to be downloaded from an FTP site, or a web service. The caveat that I'm struggling with is the processor does need to know if the enumerator ends up saving the file so that it can include that information in the reported "ProcesssingJobResult".

Comment: No the files would be processed in sequence by FileProcessor. However, in regards to having nested data my thought was the enumerator may keep multiple documents opened in the background. So when the FileProcessor calls OpenNext() the enumerator may open a parent document, and then a child document which it returns first. Then "CloseCurrentFile()" would in reality load the child back into the parent. The next call to OpenNext() would return the parent file to be processed, and then CloseCurrentFile() would close and potentially save the parent file.

Comment: So while the enumerator may have multiple files open in the background my intent was that the FileProcessor would only be aware of, accessing, and processing one file at a time. Maybe my that would be more clear if I named these methods "GetNextFile()" and "FinishedWithCurrentFile()" instead?

Comment: One more question : Are there going to be different file enumerators or is there only one implementation?

Comment: Different enumerators which can access data in different sources.

Comment: But the flow diagram is same for all?

Comment: Yes but the specifics of how the file is "opened" or "closed" may vary. That's why I'm starting to think an abstract class that defines the overall flow may work better then an interface. The parent class could defined the overall flow and when/if exceptions are thrown or caught. Derived classes would then only need to implement the specifics of how files are opened and saved. Something like this pattern: http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern

Answer (score 4):

What about approaching the problem from the other side. You have a class, that represents that nice flow diagram of yours and this flow diagram creates "events" based on transitions. Those events then can be represented as either an interface or events:

```
public interface IFileProcessor
{
    void HandleFile(string fileName, Stream data);
    void OpenFailed(string fileName);
    void CloseFailed(string fileName);
    void Closed(string fileName, bool saved);
    void AllFilesProcessed(); // maybe?
}
```

Then your "enumerator" will accept instance of class that implements this interface and executes the relevant methods.

```
string[] files = ...; // what files?
IFileProcessor processor = ...; // how the files should be handled?
var enumerator = new FileEnumerator(files, processor);
enumerator.Run(); // process all files
```

This solutions seems much simpler, but slightly harder to understand due to inverted control.

Comment: +1 for separating the concern of **iteration** from the concern of **processing**

Comment: @AlexG I think the original idea too had this separation. But in my case, I made it explicit that both enumeration and processing are encapsulated as classes. Instead of class (for enumeraton) and procedural code (for processing).

Comment: Interesting way to look at it. The problem though is I do not know the full list of "files" at the beginning to pass into the FileEnumerator like you show. 

In reality these aren't actually files but instances of a "Document" class from a third party API. I used the term "File" to avoid overly complicating my question. The Documents can potentially be nested in other Documents which can be saved on a file system or on a couple different types of servers. So in some cases I wont know what Documents exist until a file is downloaded and the contents are read.

Comment: The point of the IFileEnumerator is to abstract away the complexity of downloading/uploading/nested documents from the "Processor" class.

Comment: Although, your answer just gave me an idea. The iteration always follows certain steps GetFile->OpenFile->ProcessFile->SaveFile->CloseFile etc..But what actually happens during each step depends on the source. Sometimes "Save" means load back into the parent document, other times it means upload to the server. What if instead of using an interface I create an abstract class with abstract methods of each of these steps which concrete classes have to implement. 



http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern

Comment: @Eric in that case perhaps it would be worth defining the interface of a Document first, if as you say documents might be nested. Then it should be easier to traverse the document tree and each document can expose its status, rather than stuffing it into the enumerator

Comment: "Document"  is a class in a third party API which I do not have control over. Yes I planned to have some implementation(s) of my interface traverse the file/document tree. But I don't want my Processor class to have to worry about this. The Processor class should only have to worry about processing documents one at a time in sequence. Also the status of each Document processed depends in part on the enumerator, as I was going to make read-only enumerators which open but do not save the documents.

Comment: At the moment the method call to run all this looks something like: ProcessResult r = Processor. Run(docEnumerator, processJob); Where processJob is a collection of tasks to perform on each document. Processer reads each document from the enumerator, runs all the tasks, and compiles the results from all the documents into the returned ProcessResult.

Comment: @Eric I still don't see where the problem is. I used list of files as an example. How the list of files is aquired is irrelevant to how they are processed. All you said can be achieved easily with solution I proposed. Would you please update your question with relevant code, that you think is hard to adapt to my solution?

Comment: Part of the problem is acquiring the list of files can be a long process. Each file may need to be downloaded, and opened to find nested contents etc..etc. So I want to do the processing as the files are being iterated over rather then opening them twice. I've added a more elaborate example of my "FileProcessor" code which is consuming my IFileEnumerator

Comment: The overall application I'm developing is a macro/automation tool which may be run on a scheduled with out any direct involvement from a user. So I also want the results of running a "ProcesssJob" on some enumerated set of files to be returned as a single "ProcesssingJobResult" which I can converted into a report, save to a database, saved to a log file etc..

Comment: @Eric You just said you want enumeration and processing to be two separate "threads". Your question does not, in any way, imply this separation. This, I think completely changes how you should think about your design.

Answer (score 0):

> What if instead of using an interface I create an abstract class with abstract methods of each of these steps which concrete classes have to implement

Yes. An `interface` does not tell how the methods interact or how to process. That is just one technique for dependency injection.

> Part of the problem is acquiring the list of files can be a long process. Each file may need to be downloaded, and opened to find nested contents etc..etc. So I want to do the processing as the files are being iterated over rather then opening them twice.

**Document Facade**

A general meta-data class & and associated "framework" with injectable custom equality and comparison functionality.

```
public class DocumentFacade : IEquatable<DocumentFacade>, IComparable<DocumentFacade> {
    // this class is more like document metadata, not necessarily a facade design
    // pattern wrapping the Document object itself
    protected EqualityComparer<DocFacade> equalizer;  // customized Equals, CompareTo

    public string Name { get; set; }
    // superset of any and all properties relevant to processing. Covers all
    // document sub classes. 

    public DocStatus OpenStatus { get; set; }  // an enum
    public DocStatus CloseStatus { get; set; }
    public DocClass DocumentClass; // an enum, alternatively Type.Name, or even the Type object itself.

    public BaseDocClass theDoc;  //reference to the document this DocumentFacade represents
                                 // maybe you don't even need this.

   public DocumentFacade (IEqualityComparer<DocFacade> equalizer) {
       if(equalizer == null) throw new NullArgumentException();
       this.equalizer = equalizer;
   }

    public override bool Equals(object that) {
       if(that == null) return false;
       if(that.DocumentType != this.DocumentType) return false;
        return equalizer.Equals(this, other);
    }

    // the IEquatable implementation
    public bool Equals(this, y) {
        return Equals(y);
    }
} 


// A class for each way we want to compare Documents; each sub-class I suppose.
// MSDN says inheriting is the way to go, vice interface implementation.
public class DocFacadeEqualizerTypeA : IEqualityComparer<DocumentFacade> {
    public override bool Equals (DocFacade x, DocFacade y) {
        // customized implementation
    }
    // ditto CompareTo override
}

public class DocumentFacadeCollection : List<DocFacade> {

    public bool Equals (DocFacade x, DocFacade y) {
        if(x == null) return false;
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    // lots of inherited List stuff makes this class really handy.
    public DocFacadeCollection GetOpenStatus(DocStatus thisStatus) {
        Find( x => x.OpenStatus == thisStatus);
    }

    public DocFacadeCollection FindAllDuplicates (DocFacadeCollection otherList) {
         DocFacadeCollection duplicates = new DocFacadeCollection();
         duplicates.AddRange( this.FindAll( x => otherList.Contains( x )).AsEnumerable());
         return duplicates;
    }
}

public static class DocumentDNAAnalyzer {
    // this may be a factory, or perhaps more likely, the front of
    // of a Builder pattern implimentation
    // Besides a customized DocFacade object, we may also be able to
    // provide stuff for abstract template.

    public static DocFacadeFactory = new DocFacadeFactory();

    public static DocFacade Create(object TheDocument) { 
        return DocFacadeFactory.Create(TheDocument));
    }
}
```

[See this thread for a great GetHashCode() Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should separate enumerating over files and handing each particular file.

There already is an interface in .Net for enumerating: `IEnumerable<T>`, so I would use that.

That leaves working with a single file: that would look pretty much like your `IFileEnumerator`, except with the enumerator parts removed.

I also don't think that opening and closing should use the same status enum.

```
public interface IFile
{
    string FileName { get; }
    byte[] FileData { get; }

    bool Open();

    FileCloseStatus Close();
}

public enum FileCloseStatus 
{ 
    Saved, //File closed and saved
    NotSaved, //File closed and not saved
    SaveFailed, //File closed saving failed
}
```